# Grammar editor utility for context-free grammars in Java

Tags: java

Is there any Grammar editor utility for context-free grammars developed in Java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The one I know about would be **[XText](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/)**.
Might be a bit over-kill:

> Xtext is a framework for development of programming languages and domain specific languages (DSLs). Just describe your very own DSL using Xtext's simple EBNF grammar language and the generator will create a parser, an AST-meta model (implemented in EMF) as well as a full-featured Eclipse text editor from that.

The DSL editor looks like:

[alt text http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/latest/images/getting-started-grammar.png](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/latest/images/getting-started-grammar.png)

Allowing you to play with the language you just defined:

[alt text http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/latest/images/getting-started-editor.png](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/latest/images/getting-started-editor.png)

Comment: intuitive, simple to use, great editor, powerful - I like that one.

Answer (score 3):

ANTLRWorks the GUI development environment for ANTLR is quite nice. I've used it with ease in the past.

http://www.antlr.org/works/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I also found that:

http://ozark.hendrix.edu/~burch/proj/grammar/

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer compiler built into your app without generating any source files, take a look at  Parboiled: https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled